# What is difference, ruby HTTParty and angular $http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, angularjs, httparty

**HTTParty**

```
url      = "https://my-url/locomotive/api/tokens.json"
response = HTTParty.post(url, body: { :api_key => @api_key })
```

On the server:

```
Started POST "/locomotive/api/tokens.json" for 202.4.224.66 at 2014-06-15 17:59:57 +1000
Processing by Locomotive::Api::TokensController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"api_key"=>"5fcfe580e42944c896a49469c30aa97a384b497d"}
```

**$http**

```
$http({
  url: 'https://ernie-locomotive.12wbt.com/locomotive/api/tokens.json', 
  method: 'POST',
  params: data
});
```

```
Started OPTIONS "/locomotive/api/tokens.json?api_key=5fcfe580e42944c896a49469c30aa97a384b497d" for 59.167.21.65 at 2014-06-15 17:53:43 +1000
Processing by Locomotive::Public::PagesController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"api_key"=>"5fcfe580e42944c896a49469c30aa97a384b497d", "path"=>"locomotive/api/tokens"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

Basically, I thought they are two same methods. Seems that `$http` doesn't pass http method. HTTParty does what it requers and grabs the results correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is cross origin request, browser sends CORS preflight request before actual one...

More about CORS: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: So does that mean, that Angular doesn't handle that?

Comment: @JackieChan it is not angular related... It is about how browser works with cross-origin request. Angular works OK with such requests - but you needs to setup your server to return appropriate CORS headers for preflight request

Comment: It is completely server-side issue, it can not be 'fixed' on client...    I am almost sure - there should be something for rails to do this. Alternatively you can use jsonp or setup proxy for api on same origin where angular app is hosted.